# laravel6.0でのduskでのブラウザテストで「InvalidSessionIdException: invalid session id」のエラー発生

Tags: php, docker, laravel, phpunit

#### 該当のコード

laravel duskでの次のテストでのエラーの解消法が分からず困っています

```
class HomeTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A Dusk test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/register')
            ->assertSee('ユーザー登録');
    }
}
```

テスト実行で以下のエラー

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\HomeTest::testExample
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\InvalidSessionIdException: invalid session id

/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:107
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:370
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:590
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteExecuteMethod.php:27
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/WebDriverOptions.php:166
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:369
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:161
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php:176
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:162
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:78
/var/www/Tests/Browser/HomeTest.php:27

Caused by
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\InvalidSessionIdException: invalid session id

/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:107
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:370
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:590
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteExecuteMethod.php:27
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteTargetLocator.php:38
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:271
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:141
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php:176
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:147
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:70
/var/www/Tests/Browser/HomeTest.php:27

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

同様のエラーで検索するとdocker container内のshm_sizeの不足が原因との情報がありましたが、/dev/shmの空きも十分にあるので別の原因かと思われます
phpunitでテストするのが初めて色々と理解が浅いのですが、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

こちら参考にduskのインストールしました
[Laravel 6.x Laravel Dusk](https://readouble.com/laravel/6.x/ja/dusk.html)

.env.dusk.localのapp_url環境変数はブラウザからアクセスするアプリケーションのURLと一致しています

Laravel Framework 6.18.3
Google Chrome 80.0.3987.149
ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/252272

Answer (score 0):

・全コンテナを再起動
・プロジェクトを別ディレクトリにcloneして新規に環境を作成

根本的な解決にはなりませんが
上記の2点を実行すると解決する場合があります。

Answer (score 0):

[ブラウザテストで「Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\InvalidSessionIdException: invalid session id」docker＋selenium＋ChromeDriver＋dusk(laravel) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/u-j/items/b6ba835cef2eb3348047)
を参考に
docker-compose.ymlに以下を追加。

```
shm_size: '2gb' # 追加
```

で解決しました。